# Problema al validar un video

Tags: python, python-3.x

En el programa que estoy haciendo en Python tengo un script llamado `Validaciones.py`.

Y en el entre otras validaciones que tengo, hay una que verifica que el video este disponible:

`def Comprobar_Si_El_Video_Esta_Disponible(log, URL_VIDEO):`

```
"""
Comprueba si el video está disponible
"""
if VideoPrivate(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO)):
    log.writeError("El video es privado")
    raise Exception("El video es privado")
elif VideoUnavailable(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO)):
    log.writeError("El video no está disponible")
    raise Exception("El video no está disponible")
elif AgeRestrictedError(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO)):
    log.writeError("El video está restringido por edad")
    raise Exception("El video está restringido por edad")
elif LiveStreamError(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO)):
    log.writeError("El video es un Live Stream")
    raise Exception("El video es un Live Stream")
elif VideoRegionBlocked(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO)):
    log.writeError("El video está restringido por regiones")
    raise Exception("El video está restringido por regiones")
else:
    print("El video está disponible")
    log.writeLog("El video está disponible")
    return True`
```

Pero siempre me dice que el video es privado.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo primero sería ver que retorna `VideoPrivate(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO))` con una URL conocida. Es la prueba mínima para asegurase de que no este retornando siempre `True`

Comment: @Candid Moe Como puedo ver eso? (VideoPrivate pertenece a  pytube.exceptions)

Comment: `resultado = VideoPrivate(__Extract_Video_ID(URL_VIDEO))`, luego `print(resultado)`, y después haces el `if`.

Comment: @Candid Moe Como al hacer lo que me has dicho me sale esto: `j-jzI3wkkVk is a private video` y me sigue saliendo lo mismo (la URL original es esta: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-jzI3wkkVk) y te aseguro que es un video publico, además lo he probado con muchos videos y me sigue diciendo lo mismo

Comment: La función retorna un string no vacio, lo que se interpreta como `True`. Habría que revisar dicha función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás usando la librería `pytube` en la forma correcta. Las clases `VideoPrivate()` y otras que usas en el código **son excepciones**, y no funciones para comprobar un vídeo.

La forma correcta de comprobar si un vídeo está o no disponible es ejecutar el método `.check_availabilty()` de la instancia `YouTube()` que accede al vídeo. Al ejecutar ese método, si todo va bien no ocurre nada (no retorna nada), pero si el vídeo no está disponible por alguna razón, entonces ese método **elevará una excepción**, y es capturando esa excepción como puedes averiguar qué pasó.

Así, por ejemplo, un código que funciona sería el siguiente:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.exceptions import PytubeError

# Probemos con el vídeo que tú mismo das de ejemplo
video = "youtube.com/watch?v=j-jzI3wkkVk"

# Creamos el objeto YouTube
yt = YouTube(video)

# Y ahora verifiquemos la disponibilidad
try:
  yt.check_availability()           # Probamos
  print("Ok, video disponible")     # Si todo va bien, saldrá este mensaje

except PytubeError as e:   # Si el vídeo no está disponible capturamos la excepción
  print(f"Video no disponible ({e})")

except Exception as e:     # Cualquier otra excepción la capturamos aqui
  print(f"Ha ocurrido una excepción {e}")
```

Al ejecutar lo anterior sale:

```
Ok, video disponible
```

Pero si cambias el inicio por `video="youtube.com/watch?v=jKx5tNrsiE8"` (que es uno privado), el mismo código elevará la excepción `pytube.exceptions.VideoPrivate`, la cual es una subclase de `PytubeError`, por lo que entrará por el primer `except`. La variable `e` contiene una descripción del problema, por lo que la estamos imprimiendo. Saldría lo siguiente:

```
Video no disponible (jKx5tNrsiE8 is a private video)
```

Si quieres puedes capturar separadamente la excepción `VideoPrivate`, `VideoUnavailable`, etc... para crear un mensaje de error específico para cada uno de esos casos, pero el esquema anterior también funciona puesto que como parte del mensaje de error estamos imprimiendo la excepción `e` que se haya producido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona